# Number Guessing Game with two players

Tags: c

Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong with my program it is prety complex for me. It is a number guessing game where two player can play. It starts by saying which player goes first and the player then has to input his number either 1 or 2 and then enter a guess or either pass (players can't pass more than 3 times or twice in a row). It is working very good except that everytime player 1 starts it asks him for a guess twice in a row bu then works fine, and when player 2 starts it alternates like it should like this:

[image: Here is when player 2 goes first it works fine]

[image: Here it is when player 1 goes first and it reapeats only once]

```
And this is my code It quite a lot of code:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(void) { 

int playerNumber = 0;
int number = 0;
int playerInput = 0;    
int guess = 0;
char input;
char str[6] = {0};
int playerA = 1;
int playerB = 2;
int passA = 3;
int passB = 3;
int i = 1;
int playerTurn = 0;
int turn = 0;

 srand(time(NULL));
 playerNumber = 1 + rand() % 2; /* Random number is generated */

 srand(time(NULL));
 number = 0 + rand() % 100; /* Random number is generated */


  while(number != guess) {

   printf("\nIt's player's %d turn\n", playerNumber);

  printf("Player Number?\n");

  scanf("%d", &playerInput);

  while (playerNumber != playerInput)
   {

printf("You Have to wait your turn.\nPlayer number?\n");

  }

  if (playerA != playerNumber)
playerB = playerNumber;

if (i%2 == 1) {
    playerNumber = playerA;
    }
else {
    playerNumber = playerB;
    }

i = i+1;

    printf("Enter Your Guess, 0 - 100 or Pass: ");

scanf("%s", str);


if (strcmp(str, "pass") == 0){
    if (playerNumber == playerA){
        passB = passB -1;
        printf("Player 2 has %d more 'Pass' left!\n", passB);
        }   
    else{
        passA = passA -1;
        printf("Player 1 has %d more 'Pass' left!\n", passA);
        }
    }   
else {
    guess = atoi(str);
        if(guess < number) /* if the guess is lower, output: the guess is to low */
            printf("Your guess was to low.\n ");

        else if(guess > number) /* if the guess is higher, output: the guess is to high */
            printf("Your guess was to high.\n ");

        else /* is the guess is equial to the random number: Success!! */
            printf("Yes!! you got it!\n");

         }

 }
  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use consistent indentation.  That will make it easier to read your code.

Second, you should use newlines and whitespace to group like-lines together.  Think of writing code like writing prose, and newlines as ways to separate paragraphs.  You don't double-space almost anything, because it wastes space and is harder to read (people aren't used to it) so don't double-space your code.

Third, your use of the playerA and playerB variables is an OK concept, but there are better ways to do it.  The typical convention in C/C++ is to use a #define for magic numbers, with all caps - `#define PLAYER_A 1`.  Following this convention will make your code more readable.  Also, since your players are "1" and "2" it is more readable to use  `#define PLAYER1 1` or PLAYER_1.

You use the variable "i" but the convention for using variables named i, j, k, m, or n is as loop counters that are incremented either at the top of the loop or at the bottom of the loop.  Incrementing the loop counter in the middle of the loop makes it much easier for the counter to get lost.  Move the increment to the top or the bottom.

Do the work by hand to see what your variables are as the program executes.  Your teacher has done this in class.  Just write down each variable and write its value next to it, then change the variables as they will change while the program executes.  This technique will help you fix other difficult bugs in the future, rather than me giving you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop in your code,

your code given below is wrong,

```
   while(playerNumber != playerInput)
   {

       printf("You Have to wait your turn.\nPlayer number?\n");

   }
```

It should be,

```
   if(playerNumber != playerInput)
   {

       printf("You Have to wait your turn.\nPlayer number?\n");

   }
```

Comment: If I don't do it with a while it would not loop and ask me again my number.